# Log in remotely with a powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to manage the pc in my lab with powershell scripts executed by a "master pc" with administrative rights, now i'm able to boot the pc (via wake on lan) and shut down them but i would like to login them with a specific profile (different by occasion); there is a way with powershell to login a specific profile to a remote pc ? Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is - but you could set the [autologin registry keys](http://blogs.interfacett.com/how-autologon-microsoft-windows-using-powershell) remotely and then reboot it and let Windows handle the login.

Comment: It seems like you'd need a configuration management tool. Check out, say, [Powershell DSC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview).

Comment: I know i can modify autologin registry key but it require 1) boot the pc 2) launch the script to modify the registry 3) reboot. I was searching a way to boot AND login all pc without any registry modification (and on shutdown avoid launch another script to edit the registry to the original value).